# Combining several find() functions to show results matching all specified filters

Tags: jquery, find

I'm trying to combine several `find` functions in order to filter items by more than one data-attribute. I'd like it to return all items matching any of the filters and revert to the stricter criteria of the remaining filters when one of the filters is removed *(I'll be adding a ranking algorithm later - probably QuickSilver, but still figuring that out - in order to display the stronger matches first)*.

I'm not sure how to properly combine the different `find` functions so that they'll work together correctly. At the moment, the filters only work one at a time (whichever was triggered last). I've posted a fiddle with a simple example of the function here: http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/WZpMh/13/

---

**UPDATE -** @Sergei Gorjunov's solution is almost there, I just need some help modifying it to use OR instead of AND so that it will show products matching either one of the filters  (replacing `&&` with `||` made the function stop working).

I've also modified most of the code so that it doesn't require specifying the tag element *(i.e. `<li>` and `<td>`)*, and have updated the fiddle accordingly.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#attributes-Colors *').click(function () {
        var attrColor = $(this).data('color');
        $('#attributes-Colors').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        if (attrColor == 'All') {
            $('#content').find('*').show();
        } else {
            $('#content').find('li:not([data-color="' + attrColor + '"])').hide();
            $('#content').find('td:not([data-color="' + attrColor + '"])').hide();
            $('#content').find('[data-color ~="' + attrColor + '"]').show();
        }
        return false;
    });

    $('#attributes-Silhouettes *').click(function () {
        var attrStyle = $(this).data('style');
        $('#attributes-Silhouettes').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        if (attrStyle == 'All') {
            $('#content').find('*').show();
        } else {
            $('#content').find('li:not([data-style="' + attrStyle + '"])').hide();
            $('#content').find('td:not([data-style="' + attrStyle + '"])').hide();
            $('#content').find('[data-style ~="' + attrStyle + '"]').show(); 
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I`ve found way how to filter these items.

```
$.fn.extend({
    filterMyItems: function() {
        function filterItems() {            
            var color = $('#filterColorOptions').find('li.active a').data('color'),
                style = $('#filterStyleOptions').find('li.active a').data('style');

            if (color == "All") color = ".+";
            if (style == "All") style = ".+";

            var colorPattern = new RegExp(color, 'i'),
                stylePattern = new RegExp(style, 'i');

            return (colorPattern.test($(this).data('color')) && stylePattern.test($(this).data('style')));
        }

        $(this).filter(filterItems).show();
        $(this).not(filterItems).hide();
    }
}); 

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.filterOptions a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('.filterOptions').find('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        $('#content li').filterMyItems();
    });    
});
```

Link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WZpMh/7/

Comment: That's what I was looking for :-D How would I return results matching 'style' OR 'color' (replacing '&&' with || made the function stop working, so that's obviously not it ;-)). Also, would you mind explaining the code a bit so that I'll know how to use it (for example change it to work with checkboxes in order to allow users to select more than one value per data-attribute)?

Comment: It works if you put || instead of &&. But if you will choose red color only, it have meaning "Give me all red items or ALL items with style attribute". In this case we can do some condition in the filter - condition like `if(style=="All" && color!="All") style = "";`.
About explaining - I can explain it for you, but more better to do it in facebook or skype.

Comment: I thought it would work, but the function just stops working :-( Is there something else I'd need to change in addition to '&&'?

Comment: It's so sweet of you to offer to walk me through the code (and I may take you up on that :-)), but it might be much easier if you could add a few comments in the code. That way I could familiarize myself with it and play around it, and if I still have any questions after that, they'll be much more focused questions :-)